# gpg-agent asks for ssh password, although the private key has no password set

Tags: ssh, gnupg, ssh-agent

I am using gpg-agent to manage my github ssh key.  I generate my (private) ssh key via openpgpg2ssh from my private gpg key. Unfortunately, although my private gpg key is not password protected, gpg-agent asks me for a password (via a nice X dialog) before I ssh/git to github. Entering nothing works fine, and I can connect to github.

```
~$ eval "$(gpg-agent --enable-ssh-support --daemon)"
~$ gpg2 --export-secret-keys | openpgp2ssh | ssh-add /dev/stdin
Identity added: /dev/stdin (/dev/stdin)
~$ ssh git@github.com
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
Hi xxx! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access. Connection to github.com closed.
```

Is there any way I can disable this needless dialog? Other than that, why do I get a "PTY allocation request failed on channel 0"?

I am running GNU/Linux; Debian 6; x86_64